# grafana graph is not showing any value while select is showing

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have created a small measurement with two values.
influx -precision rfc3339 -database datadomain

```
SELECT "compression_factor" FROM "DD123" WHERE time <= now()
name: DD123
time                         compression_factor
----                         ------------------
2021-02-21T09:22:26.4883418Z 14
2021-02-21T09:23:04.5294275Z 12
```

Granfana query is

```
request:Object
method:"GET"
url:"api/datasources/proxy/2/query"
params:Object
db:"DELL"
q:"SELECT mean("compression_factor") FROM "DD123" WHERE time >= 1613895541854ms and time <= 1613902741854ms GROUP BY time(1m) fill(null)"
epoch:"ms"
data:null
precision:"ms"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
results:Array[1]
0:Object
```

but the graph is showing nothing? No Data !! Why?

Answer (score 0):

The data source was the wrong database. While grafana is looking into DB Dell the data are in the DB datadomain. So choose the right data source!